# Cannot bind [(ngModel)] into angular html

Tags: html, angular, express, mongoose

I am trying to achieve edit form with angular and I am having an error from binding value with [(ngModel)]

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Here is my typescript code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpService } from "./../http.service";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "app-edit",
  templateUrl: "./edit.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./edit.component.scss"],
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string;
  private sub: any;
  author: any;
  error: any;

  constructor(
    private _httpService: HttpService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this._route.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params["id"];
    });

    this.oneAuthorInfoRetrieve();
  }

  oneAuthorInfoRetrieve() {
    let observable = this._httpService.getOneTask(this.id);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("Successfully got data from get one author", data);
      this.author = data["data"];
    });
  }

  onEdit() {
    let observable = this._httpService.editTask(this.id, this.author);
    observable.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log("Successfully update", data);
    });
  }
}
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']"> Home </a>

<b>
  <p>Edit this Author:</p>
</b>

<form class="border">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="author.name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" (click)="onEdit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j9kb7h)Create your author model rather than using any

```
export class Author{
 public name:string="";
 constructor(){}
}
```

then in component

```
author: Author;
```

in ngOnInit or constructor initialize it

```
this.author=new Author();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because `author` is undefined. You can add a value to author throw a constructor or simply at the declaration `author: any = {};`

Or, you can display the `form` only of author is defined :

```
<form class="border" *ngIf="!!author">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="author.name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" (click)="onEdit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does `console.log("Successfully got data from get one author", data);` shows something into data['data'] ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize object author. Because at first author.name does not exist. 
Solution:

```
// declare author such as
author = {};// not null
```

Comment: Actually You shoul declare author as a known object. For example, you should create class or interface named Author. And then You initilaize it:
`export class Author {
nameL string;
...
}`

In your ts file Declare it as following:
`author: Author = new Author();`

Answer (score 0):

The answer as you see that the author is undefined, and this also appears `whenever an instance is undefined but you try to access it's properties`!
Ex:

```
 [(ngModel)]="author.name" // But author is undefined, it'll tell you that the 'name' is undefined, 
                           // instead of 'author' remember this.
    But if [(ngModel)]="author" // This will never cause an error
```

One more thing, `author = {};` will not solve your problem, you should define a class (Recommended) like `author = new author('Fes', 'Nguyen');` because {} have no property if you don't init or set value for it pro!